# Queue Logic in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i'm wanting to create a queue

example by clicking a button I will check this entire queue and with any condition that I can satisfy I will pick two players and after remove this players from that queue and create one (match)

But I'm wondering if I'm following the correct logic and if this class structure is the best or if I create a const with the example objects

> const game = { queue: {}, player: {}, match: {} };

and how would I pull two elements from this queue when a condition is met and if it's not empty

my class Queue:

```
class Queue 
{ 

    constructor() 
    { 
        this.queue = []; 
    } 

    isEmpty() 
    { 
        return this.queue.length == 0; 
    }
    addPlayer(player){
        this.queue.push(player); 
    }
    getAll(){
        return this.queue;
    }
}
```

my class QueueManager

```
const Queue = require('./Queue');
class QueueManager
{ 

    constructor() 
    { 
        this.queue = [];
    } 

    createQueue(){
        this.queue.push(new Queue());
    }
    addPlayerQueue(player){
        this.queue.addPlayer(player); 
    }
}
```

my class Player:

```
const player = require('../models/User');

const socketId = null

class Player {
    constructor({socket,player}) {
        socketId = socket.socket.id
        this.id = player.id;
        this.name = player.name;
    }

}

module.exports = Player;
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a match making-like behavior?

Comment: @dev-Junwen yess 
yes i'm trying but i have a little difficulty with using class or even a const with objects

Comment: Basically all players will be in a row, and I will create a method to get two players out of that row (and then remove) when a condition is met, and then send those two players to a class "match".

Comment: Are you using Node.js or React ?

Comment: @dev_junwen node.js  
I'm using nodejs to back socket.io and react to front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done anything like a `Queue` system before, but this is what comes up on my mind. The idea is having a `queue` that stores an array of currently pending `players`, and a `matches` object that stores a single `match` id as its key and the matched players as its value. Of course this could be an array as well.

This is just a rough idea, you will need to modify to suit your need.

Some class might not be necessary if there's no internal methods defined for the class (Player), but I used class for everything anyway.

```js
const uuid = require("uuid");

/*
  // Concept: 
  // an array of pending players
  const queue = [
    {
      id: "player-1",
      name: "Player 1"
    },
    {
      id: "player-2",
      name: "Player 2"
    }
  ];

  // current matches with id as the match's key
  const matches = {
    'match-001': [
      {
        ...players
      }
    ]
  };
*/

// Player class
class Player {
  constructor(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  // Player rest methods...
  // I.E: updateName...
}

// Matches class is a collection of Match
class Matches {
  constructor() {
    this.matches = {};
  }

  addMatch(match) {
    this.matches[match.id] = match;
  }
  // Matches rest methods...
}

// Match class is a single game Match structure
class Match {
  constructor(players) {
    this.id = uuid.v4().toString();
    this.players = players;
  }
  // Match rest methods...
  // I.E: isMatchEnded, isMatchStarted ...
}

// Queue class is a queue system with players.
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
  }

  // addPlayers add multiple players into queue
  addPlayers(players) {
    this.players = this.players.concat(players);
  }

  // addPlayer adds a single player into queue
  addPlayer(player) {
    this.players.push(player);
  }

  // removePlayers remove multiple players from queue
  removePlayers(players) {
    players.forEach(p => {
      this.removePlayer(p);
    });
  }

  // removePlayer removes a single player from queue
  removePlayer(player) {
    const index = this.players.findIndex(p => p.id === player.id);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.players.splice(index, -1);
    }
  }

  // getPlayers return players that are currently on queue
  getPlayers() {
    return this.players;
  }

  // makeMatch makes match with provided condition and removes
  // matching players from queue
  makeMatch(condition) {
    // make matched players
    const matchedPlayers = this.players.filter(condition);
    // remove matched players from this.players
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    // return new Match with matched players
    return new Match(matchedPlayers);
  }
}

// Initializes queue
const queue = new Queue();

// Initializes matches,
// object with match id as key and matched players as value
const matches = new Matches();

// Add mock players
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
  queue.addPlayer(new Player(`player_${i}`, `Player ${i}`));
}

// Create a match with players,
// apply your match logic here (array filter)
// in this case with index odd numbers
const match = queue.makeMatch((_, idx) => idx % 2 === 0);

// Add created match into matches class
matches.addMatch(match);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I believe that with this I can do what I imagined, can you ask me a question?

Did you use u.id to generate random numbers for a match id?
if i have a table in the database with match id wouldn't u need this .id?
Or would I better save this id to the database?

Comment: I used uuid for the match id. You can use xid or whatever will do. This is just a very simple concept and you probably need to modify somethings to suit your need. For instance you might need to make `makeMatch` function into a promise because you won't always get a perfect match, meaning that your match making might fail because there's currently no players on queue that fits the condition you provided.

Comment: Oops bro I adapting the code realized something when creating the match with the condition is not removing the players that satisfy the condition of the current list I did not find any error in the code

Comment: const index = this.players.findIndex(p => p.id === player.id);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.players.splice(index, -1);
      }

Comment: I coded so that the list will remove player based on their ID. Did your matched players has the field `id`? What's your match condition?